# How can i remove block of code in php?

Tags: php

H
How can I remove block of code in php from a file like this:

myfile.php contain:

```
class sample {
    public function test() {
        echo 'yes';
    }

    public function myinfo() {
        function test() {
            echo 'yes';
        }
    }

    public function remove() {
        echo 'tes';
    }
}
```

and I want to remove test method from this file

Comment: you can not remove test method by code go to file edit and remove

Comment: Tnx alot teacher :D

Comment: can i post my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can if you use something like Perl ! :P